# Why projection is not including navigation nested properties in EF Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I have these types

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Nested> Nested { get; set; }
}

public class Nested
{
    public Guid ModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Model Model{ get; set; }

    public Guid FurtherNestedId{ get; set; }
    public virtual FurtherNested FurtherNested { get; set; }
}

public class FurtherNested
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use these to build a view model as below:

```
_dbContext.Models.Include(x => x.Nested).ThenInclude(x => x.FurtherNested).Select(x => new {
    Nested= x.Nested
}).ToList();
```

For some reason this creates a list of objects with Nested properties (as expected) but a list item's Nested property has FurtherNestedId set but not FurtherNested and so I cannot get FurtherNested.Name. IE FurtherNestedId is there but the actual navigation property is not.

But my data context has the includes...

Why is this please?

EDIT: Also worth noting that by moving the toList() up above the .Select() I get exactly what I want, but it takes 3 times as long to execute.

EDIT: I am trying to get something like this:

```
{
    any other properties that live on Model,
    Nested: [
         furtherNestedId: '',
         furtherNested: { Name: '' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `Include` doesn't work with projection queries. Once you start projecting (`Select`), you need to continue with `Select` all the way down. See [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes)

Comment: Ivan Stoev got the point! Thank you Ivan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Include doesn't work with projection queries. Once you start projecting (Select), you need to continue with Select all the way down.

So try this:

```
var myModels = _dbContext.Models.Include(x => x.Nested).ThenInclude(n => n.FurtherNested).Select(x => new
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Nested = x.Nested.Select(n => new
                {
                    FurtherNestedId = n.FurtherNestedId,
                    FurtherNested = n.FurtherNested
                })

            }).ToList();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The thing is that I actually want to return an array of Nested.

In my real code my projection has more properties.

Comment: Whose array of Nested? Certain Model's Array of Nested? Then why do you need to access `FurtherNested`  Please make your requirement more clear!

Comment: Just tell me. are you trying to get certain Model's `Nested` with `FurtherNested` or only all `Nested` with its associated `FurtherNested`?

Comment: I want an object that looks like this {
some other properties,
Nested: [
  furtherNestedId: '',
  furtherNested: {
Name: ''
  }
]
}

Comment: What does {} means? Projected object? Tell details about the object you want.

Comment: Sorry I didnt hold shift :(

Comment: Whose some other properties? Model's or Nested's?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this because its a large system and I did now want to have to run through all properties explicitly that I want to return. Thats why I tried to set the entire Nested list to a property in my projection. If you literally cannot do that then fair enough. Thanks for the help.

thanks @Ivan as well.